# Использование шаблонов с less, pug

Tags: html, scss, jade, less, pug

Часто скачиваю шаблон, а там  сразу идёт `package.json` c плагинами для сборки + `less` файл. С ним понятно, загружаем, правим, компилируем. Что касается html-кода самого шаблона.

Правильно ли я понимаю что если он в `html` то в `pug` его никак не сконвертировать? Т.е. код изначально должен быть в pug что бы поправить его и в `html` на выходе превратить? Где-то можно тогда достать `pug`-шаблоны `html` сегодня?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно: шаблоны должны быть написаны на Pug, чтобы произошло их правильное компилирование в HTML. Но вы можете писать и на чистом HTML в Pug-шаблоне, если будете экранировать строку:

```
   div
      | <h1>Добро пожаловать</h1><div>Часть 1</div>
```

Также есть онлайн-сервисы, которые позволяют компилировать [HTML в Pug](http://HTML%20%D0%B2%20Pug).